# How do I handle a failing controller?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

What's the correct way of handling a completely failing controller, so that it effectively disables that part without affecting others?

**index.js**

```
const controller = require('controller');
try {
  controller();
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Controller not working', e); // doesn't get to this, just crashes whole stack
}
```

**controller.js**

```
/* failing code */
```

Comment: Depends on why/how it's crashing, and in what context yhe code is operating.

Comment: So there's no way of isolating the controller so it doesn't affect the main code? I'd thought that was one of the purposes of using that method?

Comment: It depends on why/how it's crashing, and in what context the code is operating. For example, if you crash Node itself, no amount of try/catch will save you.